# How to properly get data from Firebase Firestore in Flutter?

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I have a Firebase Firestore database as you can see in the picture. I'd like to get every document from the questions collection with their fields.
I found the following solution on the internet:

```
//in this list we store the data
List adatok = [];

Future<void> getData(){
  databaseReference.getDocuments().then((QuerySnapshot snapshot) {
    snapshot.documents.forEach((f){
      data = f.data;
      adatok.add(data);
      print(adatok.length);
      print(adatok);
        }
      );
    }
  );
}
```

My problem is that when I call this function (in an onPresed() function of a button), for the first time of pressing the adatok list is empty. But when I press the button for the second time, it contains every data which I wanted to acquire.

Did I do something wrong? Is there another way to get the data?

[The layout of the database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SGOx3.png)

Comment: If you're wiring this up to the UI, you should typically not be using `getDocuments()` but use the [`snapshots` stream](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/Query/snapshots.html) instead. But it's hard to be certain without seeing what you're doing in your `build` method.

Comment: I believe I need to use this getDocuments()  function. I am making a quiz app and I need this to get the questions from Firebase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the code below:

```
List adatok = [];

Future<void> getData() async{
 QuerySnapshot snapshot = await databaseReference.getDocuments();
    snapshot.documents.forEach((f){
      data = f.data;
      adatok.add(data);
      print(adatok.length);
      print(adatok);
    }
}
```

By this way, The program waits until it gets all the documents.
and then adds it to your snapshots.

Also you have to change your onPressed() function to async/await like the following:

```
onPressed:() async{
await getData();
/...
}
```

So the program waits until getData() finishes.

Comment: Thank you very much! Your answer means that I wasn't entirely wrong with thinking to use async programming, but I didn't know where to write the await keyword. Thank you again!